# Counting words in a file using only stdio.h and stdlib.h

Tags: c, string, file, character

I need to count the number of **WORD/CHARACTERS** *"ananas"*  in some **FILE**.

I need to **rewrite** this file with the number of words "ananas".

- Also I can use only these 4 functions!!!! *fopen(), fclose(), fgetc(), fputc()*
- It should be count Big Capitals characters as Smaller characters too (e.g. aNaNAs)

**Example**

Input file: *Bananas are edible fruits, botanically berries. I love BANANAS because they are really good aNanas.*

Output file: *3*

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){
    char filename[20];
    char ch;
  FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening file.");//perror=printf pre errory
        return 1;
    }
 
    /* Normal processing continues here. */
   
    while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
      
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;


}
```

Comment: Your `filename[]` has no name, and note that `char ch;` should be `int ch;` It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @WeatherVane filename ignore.. int ch OK i will fix.. Read start of my topic.. The code is supposed to count characters " a n a n a s "in tandem so that means count ammount of word "ananas" in file.. "ananas" = "AnAnAS" = "ANANAS"

Comment: I mean, what is your question?

Comment: you need to write the parser which will detect the words you need. The easiest way is to implement your own strstr function.

Comment: @WeatherVane how to revrite file with number of counted words "ananas" in this file..

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland strstr function? tell me more i dont know this function and I use only 4 functions fopen(), fclose(), fgetc(), fputc()

Comment: Re-open the file in `"w"` mode and `fprintf` the number of substrings.

Comment: and how I will count number of substrings?

Comment: What does "count amount of word/characters" mean? Do you want words or substrings or characters? If you look for `"ananas"`, would `"bananas"` be considered a match or not? If you look for `"nana"` would `"nananana"` count as 0, 2, or 3 matches?